# Where can I find as SIM Card reader/writer component (FOSS)?

Tags: delphi

Does anyone know where I can find one?

[Update] I have bought many SIM card readers from eBay and the software is always extremely poor. I would like to code my own - something like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16653/A-Smart-Card-Framework-for-NET

I intend to use such a cheap SIM card reader and simply write my own software. There appear to be only two major APIs. I just wondered if there was a component which handles them ...

I can't remember the name of those two APIs (one ... *might* have been ... Phoenix (?)), but anyone who can answer the question can.

Comment: but... , what about the hardware side

Comment: You need to provide more detail to get a meaningful answer. As the question is written right now, a perfectly valid answer would be `Android` with your choice of hardware (as `Android` is open source!).

Comment: You need to define which API you're using.

Comment: @CosminPrund The tag is Delphi, so that rules out Android ;-)

Comment: "need to define which API". Agreed, but ... last time I used such a program they all offered a choice of two - and I no longer remember which. Now, some folks might want to down-vote me for not having a photographic memory, and others who don't know those two APIS might just be kind and move on to the next question thinking that life's too short. I am hoping that someone who does know those two APIs will actually post some help.

Comment: Please do google search for `ISO 7816`, it's relevant for GSM card as far as I know.

Comment: You can also go [here](http://joshyfun.260mb.com/PMCAM2/index.html) if you want to scrutinize a Delphi sample code of using a Phoenix interface.

Comment: So you probably need a serial port component, and then some documentation, and then you write the protocol for talking to this thing yourself.  I'm guessing nobody has written a Delphi component yet to do this protocol.

Comment: @menjaraz +1 You could post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to head to [this](http://tacashi.tripod.com/gsmhack/gsmhack.htm) page.

You can find there valuable information about a DIY GSM Simcard interface and how to write a GSM Simcard emulator.

As far as I remember [ASIM](http://tacashi.tripod.com/gsmhack/asim31.zip) was written in Turbo Pascal but it's very instructive.

A delphi stock Serial communication will do I believe.

**Edit:**

I update the answer as suggesed the OP.

[PMCAM2](http://joshyfun.260mb.com/PMCAM2/index.html) is CAM soft emulator written in Delphi. It uses Phoenix interface to read ISO 7816 compliant smart card (Pay TV conditional access).

Comment: +1 http://www.tacashi.tripod.com/gsmhack/gsmhack.htm  has disappeared, bu I will look into ASIM. Thanks.

Comment: +1 and since you are the only one who answered, I think that I can close this question soon

Comment: I don't think so. Windows 7 has advance smart card capabilities. Please see [here](http://www.windows7library.com/blog/devices/using-smart-cards-with-windows-7/). I believe you post should receive much attention.

Comment: +1 and the answer. I don't know about "advanced", but I can use SIM card read/writers bought from eBay under Windows 7. Thanks for all of your links

Comment: @Mawg: [pcsccomp](http://www.nobbi.com/download/pcsccomp.zip) as a Delphi PC/SC component is able to connect to any SmartCard reader which has driver support for Microsofts SmartCard API.